# MVC-type validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

Hey i have model and it looks like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Morate unijeti vrijednost")]
public int Cijena{ set; get; }
```

If user doesn't enter value , my error message is being written, but if user enter value that is not int I got this message "The value '' is not valid for Cijena"  . How can I overwrite this message with custom one?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression validator as well

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

```
[RegularExpression(Pattern=@"\d+", ErrorMessage="only numbers please")]
```